# Quit loop before end

Tags: scala, recursion

How to make following non-functional, but simple code more functional:

```
def foo2(iSeq: Seq[Int]): Seq[(Int, Boolean)] = {
    var seq = Seq[(Int, Boolean)]()
    iSeq.foreach{ i=>
      println("i = " + i)
      val res = (i,i>=0)
      seq = seq ++ Seq(res)
      if (res._2==false) return seq
    }
    seq
}
```

Idea in the code is to loop given seq until first test fails, no further because in the real code the test is expensive to do. Returned seq should contain all items before and including the failed one.

Output of the code is as follows:

```
scala> foo2(Seq(1,2,-3,4))
i = 1
i = 2
i = -3
res3: Seq[(Int, Boolean)] = List((1,true), (2,true), (-3,false))

scala> foo2(Seq(1,2,3,4))
i = 1
i = 2
i = 3
i = 4
res4: Seq[(Int, Boolean)] = List((1,true), (2,true), (3,true), (4,true))
```

I made a following first try:

```
  def fooo(iTail: Seq[Int], resSeq: Seq[(Int,Boolean)]): Seq[(Int,Boolean)] = {
    if (iTail.isEmpty) return resSeq
    if (!resSeq.isEmpty && resSeq.last._1<0) return resSeq
    println("i = " + iTail.head)
    val res = (iTail.head,iTail.head>=0)
    val seq = resSeq ++ Seq(res)
    fooo(iTail.tail, seq)
  }
```

Output is :

```
scala> fooo(Seq(1,2,3,4,5),Seq())
i = 1
i = 2
i = 3
i = 4
i = 5
res0: Seq[(Int, Boolean)] = List((1,true), (2,true), (3,true), (4,true), (5,true))

scala> fooo(Seq(1,2,-3,4,5),Seq())
i = 1
i = 2
i = -3
res1: Seq[(Int, Boolean)] = List((1,true), (2,true), (-3,false))
```

So it works but is there a more concise or "scalaish" way to code this?

About performance: Code uses resSeq.last . Is it faster to use additional "lastValue" parameter in the recursive function fooo than to use resSeq.last?

Comment: Idk about idiomatic, but that early return probably shouldn't be crammed on one line like that. I'd expand that out to a full if/else tree with braces to make it clearer that it may exit without executing the bottom half of the function.

Answer (score 1):

Will that do?

```
Seq(1,2,3).takeWhile( _ < 3)
```

P.S. Thanks, @mrmcgreg, I haven't been reading very carufully. To include the first one failed:

```
val s = Seq(1,2,3).span( _ < 3)
s._1 ++ s._2.take(1)
```

P.S. And to include the comparison values:

```
val s = Seq(1,2,3).map( e => (e, compare(e)).span( test(_._2))
s._1 ++ s._2.take(1)
```

Comment: Doesn't look quite right because OP wants to include the first one that fails the test.

Comment: I need to include the comparison return value. In this example it is boolean but in real code it can have more values than true/false and the returned seq must include the failed comparison.

Comment: You can transform your sequence: `Seq(1,2,3).map(e => (e, f(e)).span( _._2 < 3)`...

Comment: What happens if s._2 is empty?

Comment: You just put the result of `compare(e)` there. The one who wrote `compare` knows how to `test`